# Separate Single column Value into multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table in below format,

```
MENUACTION         VALUE

ReceivedDetails    ACCOUNTNO v="3275402GBP"
ReceivedDetails    AGR1 
ReceivedDetails    AGR2
```

I need the table in below format

```
MENUACTION         VALUE                       CONTROLID      DATAVALUE      

ReceivedDetails    ACCOUNTNO v="3275402GBP"    ACCOUNTNO      3275402GBP
ReceivedDetails    AGR1                        AGR1
ReceivedDetails    AGR2                        AGR2
```

Note: Records in Value Column is dynamic, We need to seperate the tags in value column to two different columns(ControlID,DataValue)

Can you help in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database(s) are you using?

Comment: @Pradheep Halan,  What do you mean you "need the table in the below format", do you mean you need the results in that format, or your need the physical table organized that way for a reason?  Also, I cannot understand the format that you wrote down, can you please reformat your question.  Also, any code that you have tried, and why it is not working is the most useful in questions like this.

Comment: @Ivan: I think the OP means that `value` entries containing `v=` should be split on that term into `controlID` and `datavalue`, otherwise the entire entry is assigned to `controlID`

Comment: @davek: You are exactly correct.

Comment: @davek: I see.  nice clean up of the q.

Comment: @Pradheep Halan, I am thinking you can use the "like" with %% and "case" function to check for the format you want to split the column by actually get at the data by using "substring" to get the values out into separate columns.

Comment: In the perfect world, you would not have column `VALUE` but you would be storing `CONTROLID` and `DATAVALUE` exactly as columns. It's often very easy to concatenate values, and it's often hard to split up values. Like here. Question would be : I presume there's no other syntaxes for column `value` like the one shown. Correct ? If not, that's where the problems start. If you can't redesign the data columns, I would construct functions to retrieve these values, rather than on every SELECT statement need to find the code to retrieve parts of values.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: alter the table to add the DATAVALUE column
Step 2: Run this

```
update table [tablename]
set Value = left(
              -- The Right below gets 3275402GBP"
              Right(VALUE, len(Value) - charindex('v=', Value) - 2),
              -- and the left gets it again to get it's length - 1
              -- leaving 3275402GBP
              Len(Right(VALUE, len(Value) - charindex('v=', Value) - 2) - 1
                 )
-- exclude any without a 'v=' to avoid invalid substrings
where charindex('v=', Value) > 0
```